# List of lists and list difference computation in python

Tags: python

I have a list A (total number) and another lists of list B (contains subsets of list A). Need to find the difference between these two.

I should compute the difference between A and each list inside B

```
A=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,i,k]
B=[[a,b],[e,d,k,a],[c,i]]
i.e., A - B[0], A - B[1]   like this...


output:
[c,d,e,f,g,h,j,i,k]
[b,c,f,g,h,j,i]
[a,b,d,e,f,g,h,j,k]
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am struggling to iterate over list of list. I am new to python

Answer (score 0):

Try using sets:

```
[list(set(A)-set(x)) for x in B]
```

e.g:

```
A = range(10)
B = [range(5), range(6,8), range(9,10)]
```

output:

```
[[8, 9, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: This is not giving the solution what i want

Comment: It destroys the ordering, and it needlessly recalculates `set(A)` in each iteration.

Comment: @PavithraKC How is it different from the solution you want?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly a performance hog to be recalculating `set(A)` when they are this small. Premature optimisation and all that. There was no indication that the ordering was important, ether. But there we go.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
a=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'i', 'k']
b=[['a', 'b'], ['e', 'd', 'k', 'a'], ['c', 'i']]
def c(a,b):
    d=[]
    for i in b:
        for j in i:
            e=[]
            for k in a:
                if k not in i:
                    e.append(k)
        d.append(e)
    for k in d:
        print(k)

c(a,b)
```